# How to read this iphone app crash log

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, crash-reports

My app (named MyLittleApplication) crashes randomly when I click on a button that pops view controller.
I could use some help (to find out where should I start looking) with crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x600332e0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x351faf78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x37d0a74c NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate + 216
2   Foundation                      0x37d0a652 NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 62
3   Foundation                      0x37cfc744 NSKeyValueWillChange + 408
4   Foundation                      0x37cd3848-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 176
5   Foundation                      0x37d55a14 _NSSetPointValueAndNotify + 76
6   UIKit                           0x311f825a -[UIScrollView(Static) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1890
7   UIKit                           0x31215a54 -[UIScrollView setFrame:] + 548
8   UIKit                           0x31215802 -[UITableView setFrame:] + 182
9   POViO                           0x000fcac8 0xf8000 + 19144
10  UIKit                           0x31211b8e -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 138
11  UIKit                           0x3126b8a8 -[UIViewController beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 184
12  UIKit                           0x3121490c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 832
13  UIKit                           0x312144fc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 244
14  UIKit                           0x3125e8e4 _popViewControllerNormal + 184
15  UIKit                           0x3125e712 -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] + 386
16  UIKit                           0x31242bba -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:] + 626
17  POViO                           0x001074e6 0xf8000 + 62694
18  CoreFoundation                  0x374553f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
19  UIKit                           0x311eae00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
20  UIKit                           0x311eadbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
21  UIKit                           0x311ead9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
22  UIKit                           0x311eab0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
23  UIKit                           0x311eb442 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
24  UIKit                           0x311e9924 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312
25  UIKit                           0x311e9312 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374
26  UIKit                           0x311cf68e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
27  UIKit                           0x311cef34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
28  GraphicsServices                0x33c11224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
29  CoreFoundation                  0x374cf51c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
30  CoreFoundation                  0x374cf4be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
31  CoreFoundation                  0x374ce30c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3745149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
33  CoreFoundation                  0x37451366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
34  GraphicsServices                0x33c10432 GSEventRunModal + 130
35  UIKit                           0x311fdcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
36  MyLittleApplication                 0x000f90ae 0xf8000 + 4270
37  MyLittleApplication                 0x000f9048 0xf8000 + 4168
```

I suspect that it has something to do with notificationCenter and `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotifications` I use. Is this true or am I looking in the wrong direction?
I am calling

```
[notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]
```

in `viewDidUnload`, this shuld be enough?

Can you please tell me what bug should i start looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stacktrace you see the stack of methods called when the crash happened.
You start at the bottom and work yourself up to the top and search for a method call from your app (the stacktrace includes calls from the frameworks too (e.g. `-[UIScrollView(Static) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary]`)).
The topmost method call from your app is likely the cause of your error and you can see what the system tried afterwards.

In your case it seems that you call `popToViewController` and the iOS frameworks try to animate the transition from one `UIViewController` to the next. There seems to be a problem for the table view to set its frame and scroll to the contentOffset.

This is likely to be caused by a memory error. You get this hint by examining `Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`
EXC_BAD_ACCESS is likely a hint that you try to acces a something which is no more in the memory -> already released.

In general I would recomment to activate exveption breakpoints in Xcode:
Have you set the exception breakpoint?

- got to breakpoint editor pane
- click on the x in the bottom left corner
- choose add exception breakpoint

Now you should see a stacktrace if an exception occurs. And Xcode should be at the line where the crash happens.

The second thing you should get familiar with is the zombie mode in Instruments.
You can find a good introduction to the zombi mode in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQtPr8bkB3g).

Comment: Scrolling was the cause of the problem. Great description of possible problems!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can see you have a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`. This means you're trying to access something which isn't here, or at least was here but isn't anymore. If you can replicate the error, try using the Zombies mode of Instruments, it will tell will which thing it was expecting to access. The solution to this problem is often that you released the resource too early a resource you still need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to throw some NSLog statements in the methods just so you can have an idea of where things are going wrong.  Sometimes those iOS messages can be a little cryptic.